# ie 11: flex grow parent issue

Tags: css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I have such code:

https://plnkr.co/edit/ZAEzfAOCO0ZcSq2OR4Lp?p=preview

but this isn't working in ie, until I add height:0 (it's a very bad idea on parent element)

```
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="container-item container-item-1"></div>
      <div class="container-item container-item-2"></div>
      <div class="container-item container-item-3"></div>
    </div>
  </body>

body, html {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: calc(100% - 80px);
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 16px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
}

.container-item {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
  content: "someText";
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cecece;
}

.container-item-1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.container-item-2 {
  background-color: orange;
}

.container-item-3 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

everything works fine in chrome and ff
(my parents should expand to fit parent)

**Important!**

I need a flexible solution, my code can have a lot of nested div's (not a constant value) between body and content divs.

for example:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="container-item container-item-1"></div>
        <div class="container-item container-item-2"></div>
        <div class="container-item container-item-3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

or

```
<body>
  <div>
    <h3>text</h3>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="container-item container-item-1"></div>
        <div class="container-item container-item-2"></div>
        <div class="container-item container-item-3"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: [Support is really bad on IE11](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Comment: @Randy yes I know :)\

Comment: This is one of IE's flexbox bugs ... check the dupe and do like this: https://jsfiddle.net/h70n2o17/

Comment: @LGSon solution isn't flexible, i can have multiple parents, before body -> won't work

Comment: @LGSon why you've marked as duplicate? it's not flexible, i cannot add display:flex everywhere

Comment: I reopened your question and posted an answer. It still rely on the _min-height bug fix_, though I made it within the `container` instead...it most likely is a duplicate anyway but now I can't close it again :)

Comment: Please review and comment on my answer, and let me know if something is unclear or missing. If not, then it would be great if you could accept the answer it.

Comment: @LGSon i will. At weekend. Thank you.

Comment: Have you had time yet, to try this out ?

Comment: @LGSon not yet :) switched to MacOS

Comment: Had time to check if my answer helped you ?

Comment: @LGSon yes, checked. It's a way to handle only this code... if i have one more outer div - everything is crashing. I need a flexible solution... but ok, will accept.

Comment: If you show me i.e. a fiddle with the crashing version, I might be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an unknown or nested markup before the `container`, you could add an extra wrapper within it (here `inner`), to overcome IE's *min-height* bug.

[Fiddle sample 1](https://jsfiddle.net/t53LL549/) -- [Fiddle sample 2](https://jsfiddle.net/t53LL549/1/)

Stack snippet sample 1

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container .inner {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 16px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container-item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid #cecece;
}

.container-item-1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.container-item-2 {
  background-color: orange;
}

.container-item-3 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>text</h3>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="container-item container-item-1">
      </div>
      <div class="container-item container-item-2">
      </div>
      <div class="container-item container-item-3">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Stack snippet sample 2

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container .inner {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 16px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container-item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid #cecece;
}

.container-item-1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.container-item-2 {
  background-color: orange;
}

.container-item-3 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="container-item container-item-1">
        </div>
        <div class="container-item container-item-2">
        </div>
        <div class="container-item container-item-3">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```